What is the time complexity of the fastest algorithm for solving AM $\cap$ coAM?
I want to know the time complexity of the fastest algorithm for solving AM $\cap$ coAM, but I haven't found any relevant literature. For example, are there any problems that are complete problems in AM $\cap$ coAM?

Very likely, there are no complete problems for AM $\cap$ coAM, and there are problems in this class, or even in NP $\cap$ coNP, that require exponential time to solve. None of this has been proven.

Thanks for your answers! @Emil Jeřábek
